# Updating table from another table based of column using Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, updating

Hey there I have two tables. Grade table with data (gID) that I need to transfer to the Employee table (GradeID).

Employee

```
EmployeeID  | Name       | mgr | Job         | Salary| Comm | HireDate     | dID| GradeID
1001 | Susan Adams   | 1004| Locksmith| 60000| 20000| 2005-04-12| 1  | NULL
1002 | Ricky Jones    | 1004| Writer| 85000 | 15000| 2020-01-18| 1  | NULL
1003 | Beatrice    | 1006| Editor| 89000 | NULL | 2002-03-07| 2  | NULL


GradeID| MinSal| MaxSal| Holiday
A  | NULL  | 60000 | 40
B  | 60000 | 80000 | 40
C  | 90000 | 100000| 40
D  | 200000| 120000| 45
E  | 320000| NULL  | 55
```

This is what I have so far

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET GradeID = 'A'
WHERE Salary between (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(MinSAL),0) From GRADE WHere gID = 'A') and (SELECT Max (MaxSal) From GRADE where gID = 'A')

UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET GradeID = 'B'
WHERE Salary between (SELECT MAX(MinSal) From GRADE WHere gID = 'B') and (SELECT Max (MaxSal) From GRADE where gID = 'B')

UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET GradeID = 'C'
WHERE Salary between (SELECT MAX(MinSal) From GRADE WHere gID = 'C') and (SELECT Max (MaxSal) From GRADE where gID = 'C')

UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET GradeID = 'D'
WHERE Salary between (SELECT MAX(MinSal) From GRADE WHere gID = 'D') and (SELECT Max (MaxSal) From GRADE where gID = 'D')

UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET GradeID = 'E'
WHERE Salary between (SELECT MAX(MinSal) From GRADE WHere gID = 'E') and (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(MaxSAL),1000000000000000) From GRADE WHere gID = 'E')
```

But I need a less cluncky single query that can populate the correct grade in the Employee table based off their salary. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an update join:

```
UPDATE e
SET e.GradeID = g.gID
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Grade g
    ON (e.Salary > g.MinSal OR g.MinSal IS NULL) AND
       (e.Salary <= g.MaxSal OR g.MaxSal IS NULL);
```

Comment: @RonJeremy My query should be working for you.  Perhaps you modified it after copying it?

Comment: No I copied it exactly.

Comment: Shiza sorry dude it is actually Microsoft SQL Server Syntax not MySQL

Comment: I updated my answer for SQL Server.  MySQL and SQL Server are not the same thing.